# When to use an abstract model?

Tags: python, django

There's a form on our website that gives you a quote if you enter a to and from address. From there, you can go ahead and make a booking or just leave the website. We save the quotes generated by users for statistic purposes (e.g compare the quote and booking ratio). Currently, I use two tables for this. Quotation and Booking. Here are the tables (models in Django):

```
Quotation:
    to
    from
    price
    some_charge
    other_charge


Booking:
   to
   from
   price
   some_charge
   other_charge
   name
   # other booking details
```

I have kept them as separate models but I have noticed they are getting very similar over time. I am adding fields to both models and also have duplicate methods. Should I make a QuotationModel and extend both from that? Any other suggestions? Any theory I should for a scenario like this?